# Does lightning strike on an angle?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, with the advent of weather on my friend's SMP server, two structures have already been burned to the ground by lightning strikes.  Miraculously, the current tallest flammable structure on the server is unharmed.  The observation deck of my lighthouse is made of red wool (I've converted the white wool base to iron).  I've also made sure to put a firebreak (triple row of glass floor) between the wooden access-way and the wooden stairs inside the structure, so while a lightning strike wouldn't be **completely** disastrous, the top section is the most time consuming to build.  So, for some reason, I got the idea that lightning only strikes vertically, which led me to build a glass shield at the ceiling of the map, in the shape of the widest parts of the lighthouse.

[image: Lighthouse, and 'lightning shield']

You can see the shield towards the top of the image.  It's placed directly above the structure, and provided lightning only travels vertically downward, protects the entire structure.

---

Will this work?  Or does lightning strike on an angle?

Comment: You could use TNT instead of red wool, I don't think it "burns"

Comment: @NickT > For some reason, that doesn't sound like a very good plan for saving a structure.

Comment: @Rapida > I think it looks much better [from the inside](http://i.imgur.com/XjXnv.png).

Comment: @GnomeSlice, you're right, the inside *is* very cool, as is the outside.

Comment: For lightning to not strike at an angle, it would have to hit a square directly below the one it started at right?  I don't think lightning is straight enough for that to happen.

Comment: @John > Well, in reality, no.  But we *are* talking about a grid-based game here.

Comment: @Gnome: true, but just look at that lightning in that youtube video!  That doesn't look straight to me...

Comment: @GnomeSlice What texture pack is that?

Comment: @NotaName > I'm pretty sure that's actually the default texture pack, which I was using at the time because my usual pack didn't work properly  with 1.5.  It's been updated now, and if you want to take a look, it's called [Piehole](http://piehole.alexvoelk.de/) :P

Comment: @GnomeSlice Can I join your server? :D

Comment: @GnomeSlice - liking the new avatar :D

Comment: According to the wiki, "Lightning can go directly through blocks to hit the ground." However, it's entirely possible this was tested with commands, which I think have been established to cause lightning to break rules. Also, the wiki says "If the player is playing on Peaceful or easy, no fire will be created by lightning strikes."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It *looks like*, or is rendered to strike on an angle, but actually it only happens at the vertically highest (up to 127) solid block at its horizontal location. In other words, the lightning travels vertically downward through [non-solid transparent blocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Opacity#Types_of_transparent_blocks) with a few exceptions you won't care. This is a theory from code reading, and it seems [bckbck](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20715/does-lightning-strike-on-an-angle/21323#21323) has verified this.

Comment: The only correct answer. Visuals mean nothing in games.

Answer (score 46):

Yes, but not all the time.

The thunderbolts do strike diagonally, but most of the time it strikes like the picture below.[image: lightning]

There are also times when it will strike diagonally.
[image: diagonal lightning]

I recommend that you extend the glass shield to about 10x10 so that the lightning will not hit it at all (lightning should not be struck at an angle of more that 45 degrees)

Also, wooden stairs do not burn.

**EDIT:**

I tried manipulating the lightning again. I used zombe's modpack to manipulate the lightning by using the weather control (turned on thunderstorm with mayhem modifier which increases the frequency of lightning). However if you use single player command's "weather lightning" command [image: single player commands "weather lightning" command in a cave]
, it will go through anything.

So I decided to do an actual test with wood and a glass canopy.
[image: wood and glass canopy]

Then I turned on lightning with mayhem modifier. It didn't strike through the canopy.
[image: lightning unable to pass thru glass]
[image: another one]

As you can see it DID NOT pass through. In the end, my wood was in PERFECT condition. none of it was burned.[image: wood not burned]

Comment: @bckbck Can you give me a hard value for the maximum strike angle?

Comment: @gnomeslice i'll try to dig thru the source code and see what i can find.

Comment: @bckbck I'm going to award you the bounty in good faith that you'll deliver on the angles.

Comment: @bckbck You ARE going to follow up on this, right?

Comment: @gnomeslice im still digging through the code. no hard evidence of the angles so far, otherwise i'll use a protractor (i measured, it is 25º).
also currently i have my exams till the end of next week, so it may be delayed

Comment: What I'm still not sold on though, is whether or not this angled lightning is just DRAWN this way, or if it actually acts as though it were striking on an angle.

Answer (score 21):

[This post](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=1020&p=4213502) seems to indicate that it does - linked is a YouTube video where you can see the lightning hitting the ground underneath trees.

Your building could possibly get hit, you may want to build some more protection..

**EDIT 2:**

Unfortunately, all the testing I did below was in vain - the mod I was using to induce the lightning seems to be causing it to pass through everything up to its target. Till I find proof that vanilla Minecraft lightning does this, I'm revoking the below answer :(

Thanks bckbck for spotting this

**EDIT:**

I've gone back and done some testing to see if lightning can hit stuff that is protected by shields at varying heights.

My precious wood pile ready to be sacrificed:

[image]

I built a shield (10x10), made of sandstone at level 50, and forced lightning to hit.

[image]

I found that the lightning would either go round the shield, or strangely, THROUGH it!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

After repeated tests, it became obvious that my pitiful shield wasn't enough, the wood kept burning up - so I built another one at 100 blocks high, again 10x10 in size.

[image]
[image]

Even with this shield, the wood was still getting set on fire, so I expanded the shield on layer 100 to 25x25.

[image]
[image]

Again I found that the lightning would strike through the shield, so with a final attempt to make my poor wood pile safe, I put a layer of cobblestone on top:

[image]

No luck..

[image]
[image]

My conclusion is that it doesn't matter if lightning strikes on an angle, since it looks like lightning will strike through the shield anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure this is enough to satisfy me.  I need more proof.  :)

Comment: Slo-mo video capture, go!

Comment: Also, it looks like the visuals are on an angle and the lightning is cast straight downwards ... if you read the post later someone points out that the lightning did not strike under the tree at all.

Comment: Excellent investigation, +1!

Comment: Well, this is distressing...

Comment: @soulBit what did you use to manipulate the lightning?

Comment: @bckbck I used a command that is part of the mod "Single Player Commands", it also includes fly, noclip, teleport etc

Comment: @soulbit using the "weather lightning" command?

Comment: @bckbck Yep, that's the one

Comment: @soulbit so you pointed at the wood and used the command?

Comment: because i tried it in a cave and boom there was lightning. thru the stone. so basically your answer is wrong

Comment: @bckbck I just tried this, and you are correct - it was just passing through the shields I put up due to it being a mod induced bolt of lightning - I have edited my answer

Comment: i also changed my answer - i tried using zombe's mod (weather control) to manipulate my lightning. It only increases the frequency, so it's pretty much like lightning from vanilla minecraft.